# I am not seeing the excel files in a folder when getting data from a folder on Power Query

Tags: powerquery

Is there setting for me to view the excel files a saved in a folder when running Power Query. I can load one file at a time, but it won't allow to load from a folder.
[image: When loading individual files]

[image: When loading from a folder].

Is it possible that my IT department  locked this feature of loading files from a folder using Power Query?

Comment: `Get Data` => `From Folder`. After you select the **Folder**, power query will show a preview of the folder contents.  Then select `Transform Data` and you will see a list of all the files. You can filter to select the specific files, then open the Content.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the individual files because when you select Get Data > From File > From Folder, you are telling Power Query that you are looking for a ***folder***. So, it doesn't not bother showing you files.

To load all the files in a particular folder in a batch, select the **folder** (or really, select the folder then click on **Open**) they are contained in.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjX4J.png)

You'll then get a window that will list all the files in the folder and you can load, transform, or combine them from there.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqX9O.png)